# Ambiguous Subscript with Facebook Array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I am trying to grab a list of facebook friends, and then show them in a tableview. I believe everything is right, however I am getting an error of an ambiguous subscript on the line "for friendDictionary in user["data"] as! [NSDictionary]"

```
let parameters = ["fields": "name,picture.type(normal),gender"]
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in
            if requestError != nil {
                print(requestError)
                return
            }

            var friends = [Friend]()
            for friendDictionary in user["data"] as! [NSDictionary] {
                let name = friendDictionary["name"] as? String
                if let picture = friendDictionary["picture"]?["data"]?!["url"] as? String {
                    let friend = Friend(name: name, picture: picture)
                    friends.append(friend)
                }
            }
```

I was able to figure this out with normal strings but not on an array. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try casting `user` to a `NSDictionary` first.

Comment: That did not work